# How to model Harry Potter's Firebolt?

Tags: modeling, workflow, sculpting

I'm trying to recreate a broom from Harry Potter, the firebolt specifically, and got as far as the general shape. My question now is how would I go about making the white growth on the handle?

It looks like the sculpting tools would be the best bet, but before I dig into that I was wondering if there was a better route.

If someone can point me to another post or get me going in the right direction I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: why don't you subdivide the mesh and use a wood bump map or normal texture and increase the strength accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to loop cut. This is useful for making new edges/verts around an object. Do this and select the part of the handle, then press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale everything up so it matches. All in *Edit Mode* of course.

Additional tip:
For the tip of the broom, you can either make "hair" strands (Look up hair/grass/fur tutorials), or you can extrude the broom staff all the way back, scale it up a bit, and add transparent textures with the strands. The last one is most useful if you're going to use this in a game though.

You can also subdivide your object and enter sculpt mode to make the patterns on the broom handle.

Comment: Thanks, the plan is to break this into pieces when I'm done and print it so the strands will need to be made of something natural (plastic will break for sure). Thank you for the tips though, should help me get going.

Comment: @ColebyConner Don't just thank in the comments, that is not how this site works. If an answer helped you upvote it, and if it solved your problem consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: I did upvote, this is a new account so it isn't shown. I did not accept it yet as I would like to see what other recommend as well and marking it as answered will deter that. I know how stack exchange works, I've used other exchanges on different accounts. http://puu.sh/wVw3L/98d9ce97a2.png

Comment: @ColebyConner if you want a simple and accurate way of doing this, you could use bump maps. This requires some work though, but once you've done it it yields some good results depending on what you are going to use your model for.